# How to make LiveData observer trigger the callback once?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a situation where I want to load some data to populate a recyclerview using LiveData and ViewModel. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    viewModel.loadData().observe(this, data -> {
        adapter = new AppsListAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);;
    });
}
```

What `loadData()` basically does is it returns a MutableLiveData object wrapping the data.

Now here is the problem, the LiveData observer triggers the callback every time the data changes. Meaning that every time the data changes, a new instance of the adapter is created which is not very efficient. Is there anyway I can remove the observer after the first callback call? 
I hope my question was clear and thanks.

Comment: you can add a counter , or you can also remove the observer in `onChanged(..)`

Comment: Uh. Don't create a new adapter each time the data changes?!